# Run and Save output of JavaScript from Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf

I'm trying to figure out how to run some JavaScript from my Java class.  I know that `javax.script` can be used to do this, but here's the kicker:

The JavaScript I want to run returns and displays a PDF in the browser.  I'd like to store the PDF that's generated in a byte array or something like that so my class can do something with it later such as save it to disk.

So I guess the best approach would be to take a `String` that I have that contains the HTML and JavaScript.  Then emulate a browser page, run it, then store the source?  I'm not sure what library I would use to do something like this.  How might I achieve this?

Comment: A `javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser` might help you get the URL of the PDF you want to get, which you could then download in the usual Java way...

Comment: Sounds like a round-about way to save a PDF file? Why do you need JavaScript to do this?

Comment: Requirements that are out of my control :)  But I found an internal solution to this.

Comment: If you have found a solution, you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your problem with javascript and java you can you this lib called Direct Web Remoting:

> DWR is a RPC library which makes it easy to call Java functions from
>   JavaScript and to call JavaScript functions from Java (a.k.a Reverse
>   Ajax).

http://directwebremoting.org/